# Telling a queryset what is its result so that it does not have to query the database

Tags: django

(Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this is just a stupid question)

On my flow, I already have the object I need from the database but I need it in the form of a Queryset to be used later (on annotations and also to use the same code that is used for multiple elements).

At the moment I'm just building the query again:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id=object.id)
```

But I was trying to know if it would be possible to "hint" the queryset to tell which is the result of it. Something like:

```
queryset.result = object
```

Probably the flow should be revisited and I should not be doing this at all, but before doing any refactoring, I would like to know if something like this is possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strictly speaking add these to the result cache yes:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id=object.id)
queryset._result_cache = [object]
```

if you then enumerate over the queryset, it will not make a query. If you further filter the queryset down, you construct `QuerySet`s *without* the cache, so a `queryset.filter(active=True)` will, if enumerated, make a query.

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* name a variable `object`, it overrides the reference to the [**`object`** builtin function <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object). Use for example `item`.